# CSS overflow-x:hidden doesn't work on mobile

Tags: html, css, overflow, hidden

I put a hamburger menu for the mobile view. When the menu is closed, it's out of the screen. But I can still scroll on x-axis despite "overflow-x: hidden;". On the PC browser it works fine, even If I enable "mobile-view" :

[image: Gif on PC "mobile-view"]
(no scroll bars)

But on the phone it fails:

[image: Gif on actual phone] (scroll bars appear)

I can't spot the issue. I tried also `-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;`.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="burger">
            <div class="top-line"></div>
            <div class="bottom-line"></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        ...
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

nav
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(76, 181, 230, 0.5), rgba(45, 76, 214, 0.5));
    min-height: 8vh;
    width: 100%;
}

nav li
{
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-links
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    transition: 0.2s width;
}

.nav-links a
{
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 4px #00000017)
}

.burger 
{
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:20px;
    display: none;
}

.burger div
{
    width: 25px;
    height: 1.5px;
    margin: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

body
{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    background: white;
    background-image: url("/Grafica/SVG/bg.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


@media screen and (max-width:1024px)
{
    .nav-links
    {
        width: 70%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px)
{
    body
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;

    }

    .nav-links
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;

        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, #96A6EB, rgb(102, 199, 238));
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;

        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }

    .nav-links a
    {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    .nav-links a:hover
    {
        font-size: 24px;
    }


    .nav-links li
    {
        margin: 40px;
    }


    .burger
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put the meta tag with name viewport in the html like this?
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @Scruffy yes, this is my head:

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=”Expires” CONTENT=”0″>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=”Pragma” CONTENT=”no-cache”>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV=”Cache-Control” CONTENT=”no-cache”>

    <title>onStage - Tieniti organizzato</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style_new.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/Grafica/favicon.png">
</head>
```

Comment: Add the `display:none` property to the sidenav after the CSS animation ends.

Comment: @keanu_reeves where do you mean? after `transition:all 0.3s ease`?
Beacuse the animation happens because of the translation form 100% to 0% and the transition property.

Comment: With the help of javascript, you can fire up a function that will 1) wait 0.3s and 2) hide the sidenav.

Comment: @keanu_reeves all the "sidenav" is out of the screen, and when I click on the menu icon, I call this class in css from the app.js:

`.nav-active
{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}`

that should bring back the sidenav, that until now was out of the screen.
I tried to do `display:none` when out of the screen, and `display:block` in the "active" class, but in this way there is no animation.

Comment: And then, tell javascript to wait 0.3s and display:none that sidenav!

Comment: Like this: `myelement.style.display="none"` after 0.3 seconds.

Comment: @keanu_reeves so I have to do all in javascript, not in css?

Comment: @keanu_reeves okok, but like so by default the sidenav have to be on "display:none", and when I click it should set it to "display:block" and after 0.3s fire the animation

Comment: it doesn't work, the animation did not start

Comment: By default the sidenav should be set on `display:none`. When the user click the hamburger menu, set it on `display:block` and translate it.

Comment: @keanu_reeves yes.. is what I did.

In css:
I set to none

In js:
I wrote "Timeout(func, 0.3);" where func is myelement.style.display="none"

Comment: Well, you must be doing it wrong. I use this method here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225294/responsive-scrollable-sidenav-for-old-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem using a different approach in javascript:

```
const navlinks = document.getElementById("nav-links");
var out = false;

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {

    if(out == false)
    {
        //Show menu
        navlinks.style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(function(){navlinks.style.transform = "translateX(0%)";}, 10);

        out = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Hide menu
        navlinks.style.transform = "translateX(100%)";
        setTimeout(function(){navlinks.style.display = "none";}, 300);
        out = false;
    }
```

Before I was calling a function in CSS using javascript toggle, that was like:

```
#nav-active {transform: translateX(0%);}
```

Meanwhile, now I do all the stuff directly in the js code.

Now I have to test It on different devices, because I noticed that on cheaper phones the website is bad show. I don't know why.